# How to right-justify with hjust

Tags: r, ggplot2

from what I have been reading `hjust` takes a value from 0 to 1. 0 means left justified, 1 means right justified.

As you can see in my example it does not work like this for me. This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

abundance_environment <- read.table('/home/agalvez/data/environmental_data/vanellid/environmental_parameters.csv', sep="\t", header=TRUE)

lineplot9 <- ggplot(abundance_environment, aes( x = abundance_environment$Chlorophyll_A..mg.m..3., y = abundance_environment$log, group = abundance_environment$Depth_Nominal , colour = abundance_environment$Depth_Nominal)) +
  geom_point( size =2, shape =16) + 
  xlab("Chlorophyll A (mg/m³)") + ylab("Relative abundance") + ggtitle("Abundance-Chlorophyll A") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(colour = "Depth") +
  stat_cor(method = "spearman", size= 3, p.accuracy = 0.001, r.accuracy = 0.001, hjust=1) +
  geom_smooth(method= lm, se= FALSE, size= 1) 
  
  
lineplot9

cor(x= abundance_environment$Chlorophyll_A..mg.m..3., y= abundance_environment$log, method = "spearman", use = "complete.obs")
```

[image]

As you can see, my correlation values appear in the wrong position. How could I solve that?

EDIT:

Result of

```
 stat_cor(label.y.npc="top", label.x.npc = "right", method = "spearman", size= 3, p.accuracy = 0.001, r.accuracy = 0.001)
```

[image]

```
> dput(head(abundance_environment))
structure(list(OGA_ID = c(20L, 22L, 66L, 75L, 91L, 126L), sample_ID = structure(c(8L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 5L), .Label = c("TARA_A100001640", "TARA_N000000077", 
"TARA_N010000218", "TARA_N010000238", "TARA_N010000586", "TARA_N010000911", 
"TARA_N010000955", "TARA_N010000980"), class = "factor"), log = c(-5.57153717588776, 
-6.37156046083652, -6.50881538403584, -6.32529538161919, -6.19086429282228, 
-6.38251610427271), Chlorophyll_A..mg.m..3. = c(-0.0018, 1.98441, 
-0.0081, 2.6546, -0.0018, 0.83187), Depth..m. = c(391L, 5L, 491L, 
17L, 391L, 5L), PAR..mol.quanta.m..2.day. = c(0, NA, NA, NA, 
0, 14.83323), O2..µmol.kg. = c(271.8744, 353.1935, 227.316, 
373.061, 271.8744, 271.064125), NO3..µmol.l. = c(16.017641, 
3.880872, 22.810319, NA, 16.017641, 4.467439), Iron_5m...µmol.l. = c(0.000208521, 
0.000596423, 0.000596423, 0.001304139, 0.000208521, 0.000426156
), Ammonium_5m...µmol.l. = c(0.035179306, 0.018947516, 0.018947516, 
0.002257904, 0.035179306, 0.007189205), Nitrite_5m...µmol.l. = c(0.348001957, 
0.152390116, 0.152390116, 0.010750825, 0.348001957, 0.010129768
), Nitrate_5m...µmol.l. = c(2.06166782, 1.684819688, 1.684819688, 
4.442976594, 2.06166782, 0.689068984)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I tried that and it brings it to the top right, but outside of the visible area of the plot. i will edit my question so that you can see what i mean. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Yes! I will add it to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks a bit as if you misinterpreted the working of `hjust`.

- `hjust=0` will align the label to the right of the label position,
- `hjust=1` will align the label to the left of the label position.

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  x = factor(1),
  y = c(3, 2, 1),
  hjust = c(0, .5, 1),
  label = c("hjust = 0: right-aligned", "hjust = .5: aligned to the middle", "hjust = 1: left-aligned")
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label, hjust = hjust))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And for your example code and data you could use `hjust=0` when you place the label on the left and `hjust=1` in case you place it on the right:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(abundance_environment, aes(x = Chlorophyll_A..mg.m..3., y = log, group = Depth..m., colour = Depth..m.)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, shape = 16) +
  xlab("Chlorophyll A (mg/m³)") +
  ylab("Relative abundance") +
  ggtitle("Abundance-Chlorophyll A") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(colour = "Depth") +
  # Placed on the left, aligned to the right = hjust = 0
  ggpubr::stat_cor(method = "spearman", size = 3, p.accuracy = 0.001, r.accuracy = 0.001, hjust = 0) +
  # Placed on the right, aligned to the left = hjust = 1
  ggpubr::stat_cor(label.x.npc = "right", method = "spearman", size = 3, p.accuracy = 0.001, r.accuracy = 0.001, hjust = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, size = 1)
```

[image]